# is it utf-8 problems? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am getting stuck with this, previously i am using php 5 and now i came up with php 7,

the problem is when i am trying to echo value from database it returns weird special character and where in my previous web it returns normal. Is it utf-8 problem? i tried meta tag utf-8, and change collation sql into utf8_unicode_ci, but somehow it doesn't help at all...

it returns like this

```
â€Šâ€”â€Š
```

what i want to return

```
&#8202;—&#8202;
```

Comment: Take a minute and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: The character set needs to be UTF8. Entities are all ascii characters so latin1 can hold them. `â€Šâ€”â€Š` looks like the single characters of a multibyte character.

Answer (score 2):

What you get from the database is a UTF8 encoded string.

The characters you see is a UTF8 string **interpreted** with encoding Western (Windows Latin 1).

If you include that string in a web page whose character set is Latin 1 then you'll see the string you posted; if the character set is UTF-8 then you should see the correct characters (without need to convert them into HTML entities).

As the latter is not your case you can proceed as follows:

---

Let the characters you see are stored in the variable `$string`: you can get html entities with `mb_convert_encoding`:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' );
```

This will result in:

```
&#8202;&mdash;&#8202;
```

As after conversion you get characters in the ASCII range then the resulting string is suitable for any destination character encoding.

Note that, according to the above, even the dash `—` is converted (into `&mdash;`)

---

This is just a quick solution to the problem you faced.

I think the comment from [Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity):

"*Take a minute and read [stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)*"

is a good advice.

Comment: hey it works with **mb_convert_encoding( $string, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8" )** thank you Paolo, is it possible to encode it all without using mb_convert_encoding ?

Comment: @Fay yes. The secret is to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through and avoid breaking your data in the first place.

Comment: @Fay are you sure?? `&#8202;—&#8202;` **cannot** be represented by **Windows-1252** encoding ---- `mb_convert_encoding` is the easyest way to to the job (afaik)